# My MIPS code is not ending the input

Tags: mips

full code:    http://ideone.com/Flt8kM

I think the problem is in this bit of code though:

```
cum_sum_loop:
#while count is not equal to array length
beq $t0,$s0,exit
lw $t4, ($s1)
add $t3, $t3, $t4
addi $s1, $s1, 4
sw $t3, ($s3)
addi $s3,$s3,4
addi $t0, $t0, 1
b cum_sum_loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
beq $t0, $s0, cum_sum
```

`cum_sum` is an array in the data segment. You presumably wanted to jump past the end of the first loop. So you'll have to add another label for that.